# RenderSection removed from _Layout.cshtml, but still throwing an error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, azure

I have an MVC app running inside Azure emulator and I get a yellow screen of death with the following exception:

The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered for the layout page "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml": "Scripts".

I get the above exception even after removing @RenderSection("scripts") from _Layout.cshtml, as well as removing

```
 @section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

from the page that _Layout.cshtml references.

So, I have no idea why this is happening. I mean, I removed all of the code that's supposed to throw the above exception. It seems like my app is referencing an older version of my _Layout.cshtml or something weird like that.

Comment: as to why you are still getting the error after supposedly removing that I'm not sure. But you may avoid that error in the first place if you add  required: false as so: 

        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
        @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)

Comment: And what happens if you run your Web project directly, without Azure Emulator. My bet is that you still see the same error, so do not tag Azure, before you test without Azure!

Comment: Thanks a lot, Joel. I got it to work by adding @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false) to _Layout.cshtml. However, it still doesn't make sense why I was getting an error even after removing the @RenderSection code from _Layout.cshtml.

Comment: Btw, astaykov, running the web project directly did fix the error. So, Azure emulator was the problem. It looks like it was holding onto things.